# Python: NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I get the below error when I try to run a plot function:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb299cb3fc0'
```

I have checked out the other questions on this website but didn't find anything with `NSApplication _setup` error.

Below is the code I'm using:

```py
import easygui as gui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plots(plotLabel, XLabel, YLabel,XValues,YValues) :
   plt.xlabel(XLabel, fontsize=16)
   plt.ylabel(YLabel, fontsize=16)
   plt.suptitle(plotLabel, fontsize=20)
   plt.plot(XValues,YValues)
   plt.show()
button=gui.buttonbox("ScatterPlot")
```

Comment: Will greatly appreciate any help as I have been struggling with linking this plots() function with any GUI

Comment: The plots() works perfectly fine without any GUI, but my requirement is to call this plots() through a GUI button

Comment: What is the full error traceback?

Comment: What exactly do you mean ?

Comment: What error comes up in the console when you run the program? The full thing, from `Traceback...` onwards.

Comment: I solved this problem, I realized after further analysis that matplotlib.pyplot doesn't work with easygui. To solve this, I used:
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TKAgg")
After this the import of pyplot worked perfectly fine and I got the desired result.